# Is it possible to load different config files on starting .jar?

Tags: java, jar, console

My question is about .jar file. In my project I use json config file, which is loaded in my .jar file. Is it possible to do somehow that i can use different config files ? I have a project done with server/client sockets, and i know that i will have many clients, i don't want to create many client.jar for each config file, i want to use one main Client.jar and run it by just different config files.

If you can't understand i'll try to explain in example :

Maybe it's possible to make custom flag or something?

```
java -jar -config Client.jar example/foo/config.json
java -jar -config Client.jar example/foo/config2.json
```

and so on... I guess someone will help me.. :)

Comment: How do you read you config file?

Comment: @MauricePerry i'm loading it inside my code, but i need to rewrite somehow to make it read other way as i said above..

Comment: using environment variables for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options here:

1. Pass the file name as an argument,
2. Pass it as a system property

Option 1:

You would run your jar like this:

```
java -jar Client.jar example/foo/config.json
```

and get the filename in the first argument of your `main(String[] args)` method.

Option 2:

You would run your jar like this:

```
java -Dconfig=example/foo/config.json -jar Client.jar
```

And you would get the file name by calling `System.getProperty("config")`.

The second method have the advantage of letting the file name available anywhere in your program, whereas the first on only makes it available in your main method.

Comment: Okay, it's what i've been looking for, but.. first option, if i will be running like this, can i run config files like : 
java -jar Client.jar example/foo/config.json 
later : 
java -jar Client.jar example/foo/config2.json?

and how i will get the filename ?

Comment: @Ervinas34 in args[0], in your main method

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was 100% accurate of my question! Marked your answer and valid! :)